# What is the English interpretation of this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was reading [this article](http://readwrite.com/2012/01/03/32_more_of_the_best_and_worst_tech_tattoos) on readwrite.com and was quite curious about this javascript tattoo:

```
(function (life) {do {life.live(); } while (life); })(this);
```

[Image link](http://a5.files.readwrite.com/image/upload/c_fit,q_80,w_630/MTIyNDM0NjQ1MjEwOTgzNzA1.jpg)

So, I guess what I'm asking is, if you had to translate this tattoo/script into a sentence, how would you describe it?

I'm sure whomever got it probably gets asked "What does it mean?" quite often, and since I can't find the images original source, I'm asking my peers at stack for their interpretation :)

Seriously, down votes? Can't we have a little fun once in a while?

Comment: Live your life while you can.

Comment: This have nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: "As long as you're alive, live your life with an eagerness to state the redundant permanently on your body in an unnecessarily obfuscated way to show everyone your mad computer skills."

Comment: *"I noticed its using the jQuery live()"* - How do you know that?  Have you checked the rest of his body for `<script>` tags?  :-)

Comment: Voted to close.  The example code is clearly incomplete.  Besides, we should not be asked to debug (or delouse) human body parts.  :-)

Comment: Don't close it :-) it's humor, it doesn't hurt anybody.

Comment: Sorry, no fun allowed on Stack Overflow, only serious questions about serious problems.

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed with the current "code doesn't work" close reason, it should be closed as "Too Broad" (too many different interpretations), or "opinion-based" (again, interpretations).

Comment: @peter_the_oak Unfortunately, this fails the "... are more than just mindless social fun" expectation on the "What types of questions to avoid asking" guide: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's funny :-) Thanks for sharing this. In my opinion, this has nothing to do with jQuery. The code starts in a properly structured way a private function in which `live()` is going to be executed as long as life is `true`. `this` is the context being imported to the private function.

To answer your question, I'd say:

"Live and enjoy this very life you have now, as long as you can, to the last breath of air."

And probably: "...and don't pollute your society too much ;-)" as it's separated in a private method, thus not polluting namespace.

What a nice tatoo :-)

Comment: Thanks for taking a moment to share that incredibly well written and explanatory answer! :) Its unfortunate that others felt their time would be used more efficienty down voting and criticizing what was obviously a 'just for fun' question. All work and no play at stack :)

Comment: Yeah :-) I felt touched by the deep humor, but let's admit that it is too far away from the SO essential goals. But anyway, thanks for sharing. Oh, and enjoy your life :-)

Comment: @LordTubington I found that piece of code a little ridiculous, looks like once the while loop runs (once we live), it will never stop, that means we will never die. The passed-in `life` variable won't be changed once it's not undefined (initally passed in), and hence the condition helps the `while` loop run forever.

Answer (score 0):

More of a subjective and philosophical one. 
In essence, Live life fullest and continue living forever. :)

Comment: Another nice interpretation, thanks for sharing :)

Comment: @LordTubington /my pleasure, thanks for sharing that question too.